# Logback Logging - Synchronous or Asynchronous

Tags: java, logging, logback

Is the default file appended of Logback:

```
ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender
```

synchronous or asynchronous? It seems to be synchronous as the logs are being shown as part of same thread.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, it's synchronous by default. You can see [a config example on how to make it asynchronous in the documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#AsyncAppender).

This way, you can make *any* `Appender` asynchronous much easier (by simply wrapping it in an `AsyncAppender`) than if all `Appender` implementations would have to manage the asynchronicity on their own.

Answer (score 7):

Most appenders are synchronous, for example, `RollingFileAppender`. To enable async logging, you must wrap an appender with `AsyncAppender` to create an async appender based on the sync one, and it could be done easily in XML like below.

```
<appender name="ASYNC-VERSION-APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="DEFAULT-APPENDER"/>
</appender>
<logger name="ASYNC-LOGGER" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-VERSION-APPENDER"/>
</logger>
```